# Pivot in SQL: count not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, responsys

I have in my Oracle Responsys Database a table that contains records with amongst other two variables:

- status
- location_id

I want to count the number of records grouped by status and location_id, and display it as a pivot table.

This seems to be the exact example that appears [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php)

But when I use the following request :

```
select * from 
    (select status,location_id from $a$ ) 
        pivot (count(status) 
        for location_id in (0,1,2,3,4)
    ) order by status
```

The values that appear in the pivot table are just the column names :

output :

```
status    0    1    2    3    4
-1        0    1    2    3    4
1         0    1    2    3    4
2         0    1    2    3    4
3         0    1    2    3    4
4         0    1    2    3    4
5         0    1    2    3    4
```

I also gave a try to the following :

```
select * from 
     (select status,location_id , count(*) as nbreports 
       from $a$ group by status,location_id ) 
              pivot (sum(nbreports) 
              for location in (0,1,2,3,4)
    ) order by status
```

but it gives me the same result.

```
 select status,location_id , count(*) as nbreports 
 from $a$ 
 group by status,location_id
```

will of course give me the values I want, but displaying them as a column and not as a pivot table

**How can I get the pivot table to have in each cell the number of records with the status and location in row and column?**

Example data:

```
CUSTOMER,STATUS,LOCATION_ID
1,-1,1
2,1,1
3,2,1
4,3,0
5,4,2
6,5,3
7,3,4
```

The table data types :

```
CUSTOMER    Text Field (to 25 chars)
STATUS  Text Field (to 25 chars)
LOCATION_ID Number Field
```

Comment: Can you provide your create table and inserts for your sample data that's leading to these results?

Comment: I cannot create a table or insert data using SQL in my database : PL/SQL is just used in Oracle Responsys to make SELECT requests to display processed data, but not to create data.

Comment: I'm not seeing any PL/SQL here.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I find your comment a bit cryptic. Care to elaborate?

Comment: It looks like a question about Oracle SQL. PL/SQL is an in-database programming language for creating procedures etc.

Comment: @WNG you don't need to be able to create or insert the data; we need you to provide us with the table definition and data so we can recreate the your example and see why you're getting "values that are column names"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if my understanding for your requirement is correct, you can do vice versa for the location column

```
    create table test(
    status varchar2(2),
    location number
    );

    insert into test values('A',1);
    insert into test values('A',2);
    insert into test values('A',1);
    insert into test values('B',1);
    insert into test values('B',2);

    select * from test;

    select status,location,count(*)
    from test 
    group by status,location;

    select * from (
    select status,location
    from test 
    ) pivot(count(*) for (status) in ('A' as STATUS_A,'B' as STATUS_B))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked what was missing from my request was assigning names to the columns. adding the "as" for each element in the "for ... in" list did the trick!